# Run a task first time we execute the script but not after that

Tags: ansible

Background:

We are providing an Ansible utility for the admins to add or remove comments in `motd` file. We want to restrict any direct edits to `motd` file. Since there can be previous comments we want to retain them. This means that we parse the file only once and capture existing comments. After which the admins have to use the tool to add/delete comments. Any comments directly added to the file will be discarded.

Requirement:

I have this block which needs to run only once. Not once per execution but once only for many executions. In other words, it should run the first time we execute the script but not after that.

Approach:

To accomplish this, I defined a flag variable and initialized it to `0` like this `common_motd_qsc_flag: 0` in `defaults/mail.yml`. Once I executed a particular task I am trying to update the variable to `1` like this `common_motd_qsc_flag: 1`. Within the task, I am making sure that the task is executed only when the flag variable is `0` in using the `when` condition.

Problem:

Every time the script executes it is still running the task that shouldn't be run. I understand why this is happening. It is because during the start of the script it is reading `common_motd_qsc_flag: 0` in `defaults/main.yml`.

Question:

Is there a way to update `common_motd_qsc_flag: 1` in `defaults/main.yml` without using `lineinfile` module? Any alternative approaches are also appreciated if this an ugly way to handle this requirement.

tasks/main.yml:

```
- name: Parse all existing comments from /etc/motd
    shell: tail --lines=+10 "{{ common_motd_qsc_motd_file }}"
    register: existing_comments
    when:
      - motd_file.stat.exists == True
      - common_motd_qsc_flag == 0 # defaults

  - name: Update flag variable
    set_fact:
      common_motd_qsc_flag: 1
    when: common_motd_qsc_flag == 0

  - name: Add existing comments to the array
    set_fact:
      common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | union([t_existing_entry]) }}"
    loop: "{{ existing_comments.stdout_lines }}"
    when:
      - not t_existing_entry is search('Note:')
      - not t_existing_entry is search('APPTYPE:')
      - not t_existing_entry is search('Comments:')
      - t_existing_entry not in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
    vars:
      t_existing_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"
```

defaults/main.yml:

```
common_motd_qsc_flag: 0
```

Comment: My 2 cent: try to explain what you are actually trying to achieve with your motd setup rather than a technical solution you imagined and does not work, Try to keep in mind that making an ansible playbook is describing a state of the target system. The difference between playbook runs should only be a fact: did you have to change the state of the system to the one described or was it already aligned. The number of times you run the playbook is not important: it will always align the state to the description if needed. Your current requirement, at least for me,  does not make any sense.

Comment: I have provided background about our motd setup. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why don't you simply check if the list of comments are somewhere in the file and add them if needed Same for the ones to remove. `lineinfile` is the tool for that.

Comment: The exising comments are parsed, formatted and then put into an array. I am doing this because motd is a template file. In this, I just iterate through all the comments print it in the desired format.

Comment: All I need to know is how do I make this part of the code run only once.

Comment: I still think this is a bad way to handle your use case. Meanwhile, of you really want to go that route,  [local facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts) can be a solution (i.e. put a fact file on target with a var making it as initialized)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222791/discussion-between-suhas-srivats-subburathinam-and-zeitounator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using local facts as per your advice. Thanks much for the pointer. Here is the working code:

```
- name: Parse all existing comments from /etc/motd
  shell: tail --lines=+10 "{{ common_motd_qsc_motd_file }}"
  register: existing_comments
  when:
    - t_common_motd_qsc_check_qsc_file.stat.exists == True
    - ansible_local['snps'] is defined
    - ansible_local['snps']['cache'] is defined
    - ansible_local['snps']['cache']['common_motd_qsc_flag'] is not defined
  changed_when: false

- name: Add existing comments to the array
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | union([t_existing_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ existing_comments.stdout_lines }}"
  when:
    - ansible_local['snps'] is defined
    - ansible_local['snps']['cache'] is defined
    - ansible_local['snps']['cache']['common_motd_qsc_flag'] is not defined
    - not t_existing_entry is search('Note:')
    - not t_existing_entry is search('APPTYPE:')
    - not t_existing_entry is search('Comments:')
    - t_existing_entry not in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
  vars:
    t_existing_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"

- name: Set common_motd_qsc_flag to facts file
  ini_file:
    dest: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/snps.fact"
    section: 'cache'  # [header]
    option: 'common_motd_qsc_flag'  # key
    value: "1"  # value

- name: Add a new comment if it does not exist
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | union([t_new_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ common_motd_qsc_add_comment }}"
  when:
    - t_new_entry not in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
    - t_new_entry|length > 0
  vars:
    t_new_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"

- name: Delete an existing comment
  set_fact:
    common_motd_qsc_comments_array: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array | difference([t_new_entry]) }}"
  loop: "{{ common_motd_qsc_delete_comment }}"
  when:
    - t_new_entry in common_motd_qsc_comments_array
    - t_new_entry|length > 0
  vars:
    t_new_entry: "{{ item | trim }}"

- name: Save comments to snps.fact file
  ini_file:
    dest: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/snps.fact"
    section: 'motd'  # [header]
    option: 'common_motd_qsc_comment_array'  # key
    value: "{{ common_motd_qsc_comments_array }}"  # value
```